# Efficient alternative to np.piecewise in Tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I am currently in the process of porting my NumPy code to Tensorflow, for the sake of efficiently applying it to neural networks. While Tensorflow covers some of the basic NumPy functions, it obviously does not provide complete coverage. Right now I am a little bit stuck trying to translate the beautiful [numpy.piecewise](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) function to Tensorflow. The goal is to check whether each element in the input matrix (tensor?) will exceed the given boundaries if a certain step is added, and if so, to modify the accompanying element in the mask matrix of the same size. This is how the function looks in NumPy:

```
 def bounds_check(inputs, mask, step, bounds):
    conds = [np.absolute(inputs + step) > bounds, np.absolute(inputs + step) <= bounds]
    funcs = [lambda mask: -mask, lambda mask: mask]
    return np.piecewise(mask, conds, funcs)  # return mask
```

What would be a logical Tensorflow alternative? This has to be an op in the graph, as each epoch will involve making the next step through the search space and checking against the boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, it should be the same as:

```
new_inputs = inputs + step
over_bounds = tf.abs(new_inputs) > bounds
new_mask = mask * (1 + (-2) * tf.cast(over_bounds, tf.float32))
return new_mask
```

Comment: Is over_bounds going to contain bool values? Thanks, this looks nice and simple -- I'll give it a try!

Comment: @anna-earwen Yes, it's going to contain bool values. They are converted to  1.0 and 0.0 .

Comment: They were not getting converted by default, but there's nothing tf.cast can't do ;) Thanks again, I'll accept the answer - it works.